# what happens to application metrics e.g. CPU used by process that are not scraped in scrape interval prometheus

Tags: prometheus, monitoring, metrics, prometheus-node-exporter, prom-client

How does prometheus collect CPU information during intervals it dont scrape ? For e.g. i have my `scrape_interval:     15s` and a CPU spikes up to 90% during the 15 seconds that prometheus did not scrape ... Will i loose this important information being aggregated into average CPU used my process metrics `rate(process_cpu_system_seconds_total[15s]) * 100` ?

I just need to understand that if scrape interval is n seconds, then the monitoring data for that n seconds is collected or is it just Lost ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not "lost" but you're correct that it's never observed.

Almost all measurements suffer from errors from this necessary approximation or [down sampling](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downsampling_(signal_processing)).

A consequence is that any measurement calculation is *almost* always only as good as the data that was captured.

The problem is exacerbated when sampled data is further "sampled" to minimize storage for example retaining only daily data for periods beyond the last month.

E.g. assume the following is a perfect record of some measurement:

1,2,1,9,1,4,1,1,1,9

If sampling retrieves every other value:

1,1,1,1,1

This is almost entirely unrepresentative of the data

mean: 1 vs 3

p90: 1 vs 9

Comment: then its not possible to accurately monitor CPU spikes / memory consumption via prometheus?

Comment: It depends how you define "accurately". **No** monitoring system is going to capture every possible measurement of every possible metric; there will always be measurements that aren't captured unless the state changes sufficiently infrequently that it's almost impossible to miss changes. The questions to ask are if: (a) what you are able to capture is sufficient for your needs? (b) you can live with the error in observing some subset of all the data.